# Last 24 Months Records -Month Wise Need to fetch from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

I have an employee table, I need to fetch the total count of employees based on monthly wise for the last two years from the specified month.

Table Design

```
+-----------+-------------+
| Field     | Type        |   
+-----------+-------------+    | 
| emp_name  | varchar(30) | 
| join_date | date        | 
| emp_id    | int(5)      | 
+-----------+-------------+
```

If I choose the current month in the drop-down (dec 2022) , I need to show the output below.

```
+-----------+-------------+
| Month     | Emp.Count   |   
+-----------+-------------+
| Dec 22    | 10          | 
| Nov 22    | 8           | 
| Oct 22    | 3           | 
| ......    | .           | 
| ......    | .           | 
| ......    | .           | 
| Dec 21    | 5           | 
| Nov 21    | 6           | 
| Oct 21    | 7           | 
| Sept 21   | 7           | 
+-----------+-------------+
```

I tried with the following queries, but the count is added with Jan month (both 2021 and 2022)

```
SELECT MAX(DATENAME(MM,[join_date])) AS Month, COUNT(1) AS "Total.EMP"
FROM [EMP_TABLE] 
WHERE [join_date] BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()), 0) AND GETDATE()  
GROUP BY MONTH([join_date]);
```

I need to form the stored procedure ( I will pass month and year as parameters) and I got output as January, December not as Dec 22 under the month column, From the month value and year, I need to generate the last 24 months count result.

Comment: The title says SQL Server, but MySQL is tagged. Which one are you using?

Comment: You also need to GROUP BY the year.

Comment: I am using SQL server, sorry for the confusion, could you please help me to form the store procedure

Comment: So is `Emp.Count` the number of employees that joined that month, or the number of employees that were (at some point) employed in that month? If the latter, how do you know when an employee left? I assume, as well, you have a calendar table? What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: As a side note, I really recommend against using characters like `.` in an object name/alias, or any characters that require delimit identifying if I am honest. The `.` character is used as a part separator in object names (for example `dbo.YourTable` or `YT.YourColumn`), so using it in a column's name/alias can be confusing. Sticking to names/aliases that don't need delimit identifying is just an easy way to avoid unexpected errors as well.

Comment: You also state that you want rows for each month "from the specified month", but then go on to state that you chose December 2022; if you chose the data displayed to be from December 2022, wouldn't only December 2022 be displayed, as there is no data for after that (seeing as we are in December 2022). Or do you mean you need to display date for the 2 years prior to a specified date? if so, why does your expected results end at Sept 21, and not Jan 21?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your original query is two fold. First, your `GROUP BY` clause only included the month. Second, your `DATEADD` in the `WHERE` wasn't used correctly. Here's a minimally modified correction to your code:

Updated to sort by year then month numerically as per comments.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/49b973/3)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_TABLE (
  join_date datetime
  );

INSERT INTO EMP_TABLE (join_date)
VALUES 
  ('2022-12-1')
  , ('2022-12-2')
  , ('2022-12-3')
  , ('2022-11-4')
  , ('2022-11-5')
  , ('2021-12-6')
  , ('2021-11-6')
  , ('2021-11-8')
  , ('2021-11-9')
  , ('2021-4-6')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH prelim as (
  SELECT 
    YEAR([join_date]) AS Year
    , MONTH([join_date]) AS MONTH
    , COUNT(1) AS "Total.EMP"
  FROM [EMP_TABLE] 
  WHERE [join_date] BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -2, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()  
  GROUP BY YEAR([join_date]), MONTH([join_date])
)
SELECT 
  [Year]
  , [Month]
  , DATENAME(MM,DATEFROMPARTS([Year],[Month],1)) AS MonthName
  , [Total.EMP]
FROM prelim
ORDER BY [Year] DESC, [Month] DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/49b973/3/0)**:

```
| Year | Month | MonthName | Total.EMP |
|------|-------|-----------|-----------|
| 2022 |    12 |  December |         3 |
| 2022 |    11 |  November |         2 |
| 2021 |    12 |  December |         1 |
| 2021 |    11 |  November |         3 |
| 2021 |     4 |     April |         1 |
```

Comment: Is it possible to shows the records in descending order.

Comment: Is it possible to shows the records in descending order.
If i edit your fiddle to add (4/6/2021) (April) its coming at the top.
https://dbfiddle.uk/BnfSzUIu (i have order by desc for the date but its throwing error-Column 'EMP_TABLE.join_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Please help me with this

Comment: It's possible. The problem is that you are only using the month name instead of the month number. So when you try to sort the dates, you were sorting the month alphabetically. When you tried to modify my fiddle, you were trying to sort by date... which would not summarize by month, rather it would summarize by the day. So I just updated my fiddle to sort by year then month. I put the original query in a CTE so that we can do the sorting in the main SELECT at the bottom easier.